# How to apply Excel operation into SQL server Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently using SSMS 2008.

I would like to complete the operation, using SSMS and described in the Excel screenshot.

I have two tables joined, one having a positive count for when an employee's start working and one with a negative count for when the employee's leave. I am looking to have a column showing the count of employee's per hour. 
I appreciate any help on this matter, 
Thank you,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative method to `SUM OVER` is a self-join, with an aggregation on the lower or equal values.

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE TestEmployeeRegistration (
  [Date] DATE, 
  [Time] TIME, 
  [Employees] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY ([Date], [Time])
);

INSERT INTO TestEmployeeRegistration
([Date], [Time], [Employees]) VALUES
('2019-11-01', '08:00', 2),
('2019-11-01', '09:00', 5),
('2019-11-01', '10:00', 3),
('2019-11-01', '12:00',-5),
('2019-11-01', '13:00', 2),
('2019-11-01', '14:00',-5);
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT t.[Date], t.[Time], t.[Employees]
, SUM(t2.[Employees]) AS [Total available]
FROM [TestEmployeeRegistration] t
JOIN [TestEmployeeRegistration] t2 
  ON t2.[Date] = t.[Date]
 AND t2.[Time] <= t.[Time]
GROUP BY t.[Date], t.[Time], t.[Employees]
ORDER BY t.[Date], t.[Time];
```

When using the window function of `SUM`, then I advice a partition by the "Date".

```
SELECT *
, SUM([Employees]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Time]) AS [Total available]
FROM [TestEmployeeRegistration]
ORDER BY [Date], [Time];
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/RLW91501)

Answer (score 1):

It is running total and could be implemented using [windowed SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT *, SUM(Employee) OVER(ORDER BY [Date], [Time]) as Total_available
FROM tab
ORDER BY [Date], [Time];
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76635c/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Dates Date,Times Time, EmployeesAvailable int)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Dates,Times,EmployeesAvailable) VALUES('2019-11-01','08:00',2)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Dates,Times,EmployeesAvailable) VALUES('2019-11-01','09:00',5)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Dates,Times,EmployeesAvailable) VALUES('2019-11-01','10:00',3)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Dates,Times,EmployeesAvailable) VALUES('2019-11-01','12:00',-5)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Dates,Times,EmployeesAvailable) VALUES('2019-11-01','13:00',2)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Dates,Times,EmployeesAvailable) VALUES('2019-11-01','14:00',-5)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Dates,Times,EmployeesAvailable,
           SUM(EmployeesAvailable) OVER(ORDER BY Dates,Times) AS 'Total Available'
FROM MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76635c/1/0)**:

```
|      Dates |            Times | EmployeesAvailable | Total Available |
|------------|------------------|--------------------|-----------------|
| 2019-11-01 | 08:00:00.0000000 |                  2 |               2 |
| 2019-11-01 | 09:00:00.0000000 |                  5 |               7 |
| 2019-11-01 | 10:00:00.0000000 |                  3 |              10 |
| 2019-11-01 | 12:00:00.0000000 |                 -5 |               5 |
| 2019-11-01 | 13:00:00.0000000 |                  2 |               7 |
| 2019-11-01 | 14:00:00.0000000 |                 -5 |               2 |
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is a duplicate of the answer which posted 41 mn before yours.